# Can a US LPR who changed their residency from California to Washington between Nov 2021 and summer 2022 opt ​out of the Washington long-term-care tax?

Tags: united-states, insurance, california, payroll-taxes, washington

Can a US lawful permanent resident who changed their residency from California to Washington state between November 2021 and summer 2022 opt out of the newly established long-term-care payroll tax?

E.g. I wonder whether they could buy a private policy
in Washington state before November 1, 2021 even before they became a Washington resident, so that they can later apply to opt out of the long-term-care payroll tax by the end of 2022 once they have become a Washington resident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they could buy a private policy in Washington state before November 1, 2021 even before they became a Washington resident, so that they can later apply to opt out of the long-term-care payroll tax by the end of 2022 once they have become a Washington resident. However, most (and I believe, >95% if not 100%) insurers have stopped taking applications.